# Amazon EMR streaming Could not find any valid local directory for output

Tags: hadoop, emr, hadoop-streaming, amazon-emr, mrjob

I am getting following logs(at bottom of question) in stderr of failed EMR process. Can someone explain what is going on? I can not understand the traceback properly.

And what is the solution.

I am using python mrjob framework to run the streaming job. there are 12 instances in the cluster of type c4.xlarge (I have also tried m4.xlarge)

mrjob version `mrjob==0.5.6`

and following is the command used to run mrjob

```
python emr/emr.py -r emr --no-output --output-dir s3://<bucketname>/output/   --bootstrap 'sudo pip install boto mrjob'  --ec2-instance-type c4.xlarge --num-ec2-instances 12 --conf emr/mrjob.conf --cleanup NONE --emr-api-param Instances.Ec2SubnetId=<subnet id> --aws-region 'us-east-1' s3://<bucketname>/input/
```

stderr Logs

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in InMemoryMerger - Thread to merge in-memory shuffled map-outputs
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for output/attempt_1489564674361_0001_r_000016_1/map_1407.out
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnOutputFiles.getInputFileForWrite(YarnOutputFiles.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl$InMemoryMerger.merge(MergeManagerImpl.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeThread.run(MergeThread.java:94)

Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in InMemoryMerger - Thread to merge in-memory shuffled map-outputs
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for output/attempt_1489564674361_0001_r_000016_2/map_1023.out
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnOutputFiles.getInputFileForWrite(YarnOutputFiles.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl$InMemoryMerger.merge(MergeManagerImpl.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeThread.run(MergeThread.java:94)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: Error while doing final merge 
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for output/attempt_1489564674361_0001_r_000009_1/map_1373.out
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnOutputFiles.getInputFileForWrite(YarnOutputFiles.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.finalMerge(MergeManagerImpl.java:711)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.close(MergeManagerImpl.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:158)
    ... 6 more

Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in InMemoryMerger - Thread to merge in-memory shuffled map-outputs
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for output/attempt_1489564674361_0001_r_000009_2/map_793.out
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnOutputFiles.getInputFileForWrite(YarnOutputFiles.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl$InMemoryMerger.merge(MergeManagerImpl.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeThread.run(MergeThread.java:94)

Streaming Command Failed!
```